# Calculate date difference between Last modified date of a file and NOW using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, ksh, date

I am trying to calculate the time elapsed since the log file was last updated.

I guess following commands will be used

```
lastUpdate=$(date -r myLogFile.log)
now=$(date)
```

How can I subtract them and get result for number of seconds elapsed?

Comment: Use `+%s` (seconds from EPOC) of `date` output formatting option.

Comment: you meant lastUpdate=$(date -r myLogFile.log +%s)??? i m not able to get the difference stored in variable and i am new to Shell scripting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lastUpdate="$(stat -c %Y myLogFile.log)"
now="$(date +%s)"
let diff="${now}-${lastUpdate}"
```

Answer (score 3):

compare the two outputs to get the number of seconds between now and the modified date

```
stat -c %Y file  vs date +%s
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there! Just tell `date` to use a format on which computation is easy.

```
lastUpdate=$(date -r myLogFile.log +%s)
now=$(date +%s)
file_age=$((now - lastUpdate))
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

> stat -c %Y /path/to/file | echo `expr $(date +%s) - $(cat)`

Comment: gives me "cat: -: input/output error   expr: syntaxerror"