# How to get the difference between modified date and current date in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi"
path="/home/alert/VideoApplicationAPI.v1/logs"
dayDiff=365

DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
for filename in $path/*.*; do
    modDate=$(stat -c %y  "$filename") 
    #modDate=$(date -r   "$filename"+%s) 
    modDate=${modDate%%  *}
    echo $filename:$modDate

    #lastUpdate=$(stat -c %y "$filename")
    now="$(date +%s)"
    diff="${now}-${lastUpdate}"
done

echo $DATE
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to U&L! would you please elaborate more on your question and add some context into your asking question by [edit]ing. please also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. also check out this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187966/72456 which is what you need?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences

Comment: You should reduce the code to the essential parts.

Answer (score 1):

This is close to a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831765/find-difference-between-two-dates-in-bash). Adapting their script to your format gives us this set of commands:

```
echo "$(( $(date -d "$d2" +%s) - $(date -d "$d1" +%s) )) / 86400" | bc -l
```

where $d1 is the smaller (earlier date) and $d2 is the larger (later) date.

So, as far as I can tell, this should do the trick:

```
echo "$(( $(date -d "$modDate" +%s) - $(date -d "$now" +%s) )) / 86400" | bc -l
```

To clarify,

```
bc -l
```

Is, according to its manpage,

> ...a  language that supports arbitrary precision numbers with interactive execution of statements.
>          There are some similarities in the syntax to the C programming language.

It allows you to get decimal numbers in your answer, as most shells only support integer division.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to modify here, as far as I know, `stat -c` only works on GNU stat, and `stat -c %y` gives the output in the format `2019-03-14 14:21:32.704211521 +0200`. You're trying to remove anything after a double space, but there isn't one.

---

In any case, if you want to do arithmetic on the timestamp, it's better to just take it as seconds since the Epoch, i.e. `-c %Y`, not `-c %y`. Then, to get the difference (in seconds), you can use arithmetic expansion `$(( .. ))` in the shell:

```
$ diff=$(( "$(date +%s)" - "$(stat -c %Y "$file")" ))
$ echo $diff
86527
```

To get that that as hours, minutes and seconds, just make the appropriate divisions and take the remainders:

```
$ s=$(( diff % 60 )); m=$(( diff / 60 % 60 )); h=$(( diff / 3600 ))
$ printf "%d:%02d:%02d\n" "$h" "$m" "$s"
24:02:07
```

Or use e.g. `bc` to get the time in fractional days, as [@Pheric's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506411/170373) shows.